# Redirecting all non http to www https using nginx

Tags: nginx

i have been scratching my head over this problem for the past 2 days and i cant seem to get this working. I am trying to redirect all non-www http and non-www https connections to www-https via nginx for my website. Here is the conf. file that i am using

```
# Centmin Mod Getting Started Guide
# must read http://centminmod.com/getstarted.html

# redirect from non-www to www 
# uncomment, save file and restart Nginx to enable
# if unsure use return 302 before using return 301
server {
        #listen   80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
   }

server {
#listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
ssl    on;
ssl_dhparam /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/example.com/dhparam.pem;
ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/example.com/example.com_combined.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/example.com/example.com.key;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl_include.conf;
server_name www.example.com;

# mozilla recommended
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!CAMELLIA:!DES-CBC3-SHA;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
add_header Alternate-Protocol  443:npn-spdy/3;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
#add_header  X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
#add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
#spdy_headers_comp 5;
ssl_buffer_size 1400;
ssl_session_tickets on;

# enable ocsp stapling
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=10m;
resolver_timeout 10s;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/example.com/beegeekn.net_combined.crt; 

# ngx_pagespeed & ngx_pagespeed handler
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeed.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeedhandler.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/pagespeedstatslog.conf;

# limit_conn limit_per_ip 16;
# ssi  on;

access_log /home/nginx/domains/example.com/log/access.log combined buffer=256k flush=60m;
error_log /home/nginx/domains/example.com/log/error.log;

root /home/nginx/domains/example.com/public;

# prevent access to ./directories and files
location ~ (?:^|/)\. {
deny all;
}  

location / {

# block common exploits, sql injections etc
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/block.conf;

# Enables directory listings when index file not found
#autoindex  on;

# Shows file listing times as local time
#autoindex_localtime on;

# Enable for vBulletin usage WITHOUT vbSEO installed
# More example Nginx vhost configurations at
# http://centminmod.com/nginx_configure.html
try_files   $uri $uri/ @handler;
index index.html index.php;
expires 30d;

}

location @handler {
rewrite / /index.php;
}

location ~ .php/ {
rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

location ~ .php$ {
#if(!-e $request_filename) {
#  rewrite / /index.php last;
#}

expires  off;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
include fastcgi_params;

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
expires 1d;
log_not_found off;
}

}

# include /usr/local/nginx/conf/staticfiles.conf;
# include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
# include /usr/local/nginx/conf/drop.conf;
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/errorpage.conf;
# include /usr/local/nginx/conf/vts_server.conf;
}
```

Im a complete noob when it comes to these config files, ive been trying various settings from google but havent come to a solid conclusion as yet. Thank you

EDIT

Finally found a work around

```
server {
server_name          exmaple.com;
ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/example.com/example.com_combined.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/example.com/example.com.key;
listen               *:80;
listen               *:443 ssl;
#listen               [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
#listen               [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;

return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

#
# Redirect all non-encrypted to encrypted
#
server {
server_name          www.example.com;
listen               *:80;
#listen               [::]:80;

return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

#
# There we go!
#
server {
server_name          www.example.com;
ssl_dhparam          /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/example.com/dhparam.pem;
ssl_certificate           /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/example.com/example.com_combined.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl/example.com/example.com.key;
listen               *:443 ssl;
#listen               [::]:443 ssl;
```

Comment: What specific errors are you running into? Was there something in particular that wasn't clear about the Nginx documentation? Try getting just the "non-www http" redirect working, then do the "non-www https" redirect next.

Comment: Error im running into is when i try to access my website via example.com or www.example.com, browser shows a centminmod page. I have to specifically use https in order to access the site

Answer (score 1):

You should create different server blocks like in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www

No-www to https://www

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ## here goes the rest of your conf...
}
```

Comment: The first `server` block may be problematic without appropriate SSL config (certificates, at the least).

Comment: So for every server block you suggest that i add ssl certificates paths?

Comment: Yes, for both of them, as they both listen for connections on 443 so have to respond with a certificate.